# activity screen containing googlemap v2 is black when loading polygons

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I am using the code from google maps v2 to draw polygons on loading maps v2 .It loads 300+ polygons in 5 secs but it shows black screen till 5 secs and does not display anything on the screen.How do I show map or should I display loading.. msg till it displays the maps ??I really appreciate any help .I tried many ways but still see black screen as its loading polygon onthe main thread.Thanks in Advance.

```
  LatLng allLatLng= new LatLng((lat1),(long1));
   all.add(allLatLng);

polygon = googleMap.addPolygon(new PolygonOptions()
                           .addAll(all)
                           .fillColor(Color.Yellow)
                           .strokeColor(Color.blue)
                       );
```

Comment: Can you post some code that shows how/what you are doing. Could be a lot of things bottlenecking you right now

Comment: Thanks Selecsosi for looking into it.I have lots of geo-coordinates which I am parsing with json and adding then as polygons as there are many geo-coordinates it does take time which is ok but how can I avoid black screen till polygons are loaded.I would appreciate any help.Its exactly as I have explained json----->geocoords(latlng)--->addploygons ..Thats it .

Comment: The issue is where/how you are doing that, not the adding it to a map. Possibly you are parsing the response and trying to construct all of the polygons in the UI thread (blocking it so the rendering of the map is not finishing), and it would be better spent parsing your response in a thread and then only rendering them once the response has been parsed. Can you provide a bit more context?

Comment: Thats exactly right I am parsing the json from assets folder in Oncreate method without any thread or async .Can you suggest me some thing .I heard that I cannot add polygon in the doinBackground() in async is it true? What should my approach be ?

Comment: You can parse the json objects into the POJO's (list of list of latlngs maybe) and have the asynctask return that POJO to the do in `onPostExecute` method. Then you can just iterate over the list to construct the polygons in the `onPostExecute` and hopefully by the time you have parsed the object, the map fragment should have already been rendered.

Answer (score 0):

Example to go with the comments

```
//in onCreate
String json_string = getJsonStringStuff();
new AsyncTask<String, Void, List<List<LatLng>>>() {

    @Override protected List<List<LatLng>> doInBackground(String... params) {
            String json = params[0];
            List<List<LatLng>> mLatLngList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<LatLng>>();
            // Parse the json into the list
            return mLatLngList;
    }

    @Override protected void onPostExecute(List<List<LatLng>> result) {
        drawPolygonsToMap(result);
    }

}.execute(json_string);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use This to prevent black background

```
<fragment
                    android:id="@+id/location_map_fragment"
                    android:name="com.app.appname.TransparentSupportMapFragment"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/white" />

/**
 * 
 * To prevent black background of map in ScrollView
 *
 */
public class TransparentSupportMapFragment extends SupportMapFragment {

    public TransparentSupportMapFragment() {

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup view, Bundle savedInstance) {
        View layout = super.onCreateView(inflater, view, savedInstance);

        FrameLayout frameLayout = new FrameLayout(getActivity());
        frameLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));
        ((ViewGroup) layout).addView(frameLayout,
            new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        return layout;
    }


    public static TransparentSupportMapFragment newInstance(String abc) {
        TransparentSupportMapFragment tsf = new TransparentSupportMapFragment();

        return tsf;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you read the question? He isn't rendering the map in a scrollview